# Python: Write all file names in a directory and its subdirectories into a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

My problem is as follows. I want to list all the file names in my directory and its subdirectories and have that output printed in a txt file. Now this is the code I have so far:

```
import os

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('\Users\user\Desktop\Test_Py'):
   for filename in files:
     f = os.path.join(path, filename)
     a = open("output.txt", "w")
     a.write(str(f))
```

This lists the names of the files in the folders (there are 6) but each new file overwrites the old so there is only one file name in the output.txt file at any given time. How do I change this code so that it writes all of the file names in the output.txt file?

Comment: Move the `open` statment outside the loops.

Comment: Did you search SO? I was just reading almost an exact duplicate of this from a while ago...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

don't open a file in your `for` loop. open it before your `for` loop

like this

```
import os

a = open("output.txt", "w")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test_Py'):
   for filename in files:
     f = os.path.join(path, filename)
     a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

Or using a context manager (which is better practice):

```
import os

with open("output.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test_Py'):
       for filename in files:
         f = os.path.join(path, filename)
         a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

Comment: And you should be opening a file using the `with` statement so that the file will close automatically when the loops finish.

Comment: it's better to use ***with*** while the opened file will be closed after complete the process. i.e., "with open("output.txt", "w") as a"

Comment: Might want some linebreaks in there somewhere, too. :^)

Answer (score 6):

You are opening the file in write mode. You need append mode. See the [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) for details.

change

```
a = open("output.txt", "w")
```

to

```
a = open("output.txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to write only File name from a folder.

```
import os

a = open("output.txt", "w")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\temp'):
   for filename in files:
      a.write(filename + os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid creating new lines in the text file include `newline=''` within the context manager. You won't have to format your text file later.

Code to write names of all files in a folder/directory:

```
file_path = 'path_containing_files'
with open("Filenames.txt", mode='w', newline='') as fp:
    for file in os.listdir(file_path):
        f = os.path.join(file_path, file)
        fp.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

If you want to write the file names of a particular file type eg. XML, you can add an `if` condition:

```
file_path = 'path_containing_files'
with open("Filenames.txt", mode='w', newline='') as fp:
    for file in os.listdir(file_path):
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            f = os.path.join(file_path, file)
            fp.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```